# Error regarding dataset creation with prediction in R

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

```
            id power  training     hr    fr    VE  absVO2    VCO2  PETCO2     VES     QC     IC    WCI    RVSi     RVS     VTD     FE body_mass percent_absVO2 percent_power    relVO2 percent_relVO2 group temps
1  AC12-PRD-C1    25    linear  88.75 22.75 22.75 0.73900 0.66700 39.2925  88.650  8.025  3.975  4.825 1768.75  876.00 143.025 62.050      84.0       49.34068      21.73913  8.797619       49.34068   CHD     1
2  AC12-PRD-C1    40    linear  93.25 23.00 23.75 0.81975 0.71500 39.6200  87.375  8.050  3.975  4.825 1759.50  871.75 141.625 61.725      84.0       54.73210      34.78261  9.758929       54.73210   CHD     1
3  AC12-PRD-C1    55    linear  99.75 22.75 26.75 0.95125 0.85400 41.4100  93.375  9.175  4.550  5.525 1540.50  763.00 150.325 62.100      84.0       63.51193      47.82609 11.324405       63.51193   CHD     1
4  AC12-PRD-C1    70    linear 109.75 23.00 32.50 1.07525 1.04700 42.0150  93.825 10.025  4.925  6.000 1414.25  700.50 145.750 64.375      84.0       71.79102      60.86957 12.800595       71.79102   CHD     1
5  AC12-PRD-C1    85    linear 118.75 22.75 39.50 1.19900 1.25125 41.8425  97.375 11.225  5.575  6.750 1260.75  624.50 148.975 65.325      84.0       80.05341      73.91304 14.273810       80.05341   CHD     1
6  AC12-PRD-C1   100    linear 127.00 26.00 48.25 1.34575 1.51850 41.0950 100.900 12.550  6.225  7.525 1127.75  558.75 154.225 65.475      84.0       89.85144      86.95652 16.020833       89.85144   CHD     1
7  AC12-PRD-C1   115    linear 135.75 28.00 55.75 1.49775 1.76025 40.7275 104.475 13.950  6.875  8.375 1014.00  502.25 157.975 66.250      84.0      100.00000     100.00000 17.830357      100.00000   CHD     1
8  AC12-PRD-C2    25    linear  84.25 20.50 20.75 0.67625 0.59950 38.9575 102.700  8.650  4.275  5.575 1775.00  879.50 216.450 48.350      84.8       40.10378      17.24138  7.974646       40.10378   CHD     2
9  AC12-PRD-C2    40    linear  89.25 20.50 23.25 0.73350 0.66225 38.5500 111.625  9.725  4.800  6.250 1567.75  776.75 217.800 51.825      84.8       43.49889      27.58621  8.649764       43.49889   CHD     2
10 AC12-PRD-C2    55    linear  96.25 22.25 26.75 0.83550 0.77500 38.3350 101.300  9.325  4.625  6.000 1619.75  802.75 202.700 50.350      84.8       49.54781      37.93103  9.852594       49.54781   CHD     2
11 AC12-PRD-C2    70    linear 102.25 21.75 32.50 1.06250 1.01550 39.6525 103.550 10.350  5.125  6.625 1459.00  723.00 194.050 53.675      84.8       63.00964      48.27586 12.529481       63.00964   CHD     2
12 AC12-PRD-C2    85    linear 110.75 22.25 37.75 1.18075 1.19225 40.1300 100.825 10.650  5.275  6.825 1424.00  705.25 194.250 51.900      84.8       70.02224      58.62069 13.923939       70.02224   CHD     2
13 AC12-PRD-C2   100    linear 118.25 23.00 42.75 1.35100 1.40300 41.1500 108.950 12.375  6.100  7.950 1225.50  606.75 197.325 55.175      84.8       80.11861      68.96552 15.931604       80.11861   CHD     2
14 AC12-PRD-C2   115    linear 129.25 24.75 51.25 1.50650 1.65650 40.7575 107.625 13.275  6.550  8.525 1133.50  561.50 201.225 53.525      84.8       89.34025      79.31034 17.765330       89.34025   CHD     2
15 AC12-PRD-C2   130    linear 136.25 26.50 58.75 1.57325 1.83200 39.6750 108.925 14.375  7.125  9.250 1045.75  518.25 196.025 55.675      84.8       93.29874      89.65517 18.552476       93.29874   CHD     2
16 AC12-PRD-C2   145    linear 147.50 29.75 70.00 1.68625 2.07350 38.1600 104.875 15.025  7.450  9.600 1010.75  500.75 185.400 56.825      84.8      100.00000     100.00000 19.885024      100.00000   CHD     2
17 AL13-PRD-C1    25 nonlinear  69.50 16.50 24.00 0.66125 0.58050 31.2275 101.825  7.175  3.500  4.450 2126.50 1037.25 220.850 48.550      85.5       41.36691      19.23077  7.733918       41.36691   CHD     1
18 AL13-PRD-C1    40 nonlinear  73.00 17.50 26.50 0.74850 0.66425 32.1025 107.850  7.775  3.775  4.850 1942.00  947.25 242.825 48.000      85.5       46.82515      30.76923  8.754386       46.82515   CHD     1
19 AL13-PRD-C1    55 nonlinear  83.25 15.50 29.00 0.85500 0.79425 33.6650 110.250  9.075  4.375  5.650 1706.00  832.50 233.500 47.325      85.5       53.48764      42.30769 10.000000       53.48764   CHD     1
20 AL13-PRD-C1    70 nonlinear  93.75 16.00 36.50 0.98450 0.99925 34.5325 114.650 10.425  5.075  6.525 1462.00  713.25 233.075 49.175      85.5       61.58899      53.84615 11.514620       61.58899   CHD     1
21 AL13-PRD-C1    85 nonlinear 104.50 16.00 44.75 1.14950 1.23475 34.4225 120.650 12.150  5.925  7.550 1249.25  609.25 233.575 51.775      85.5       71.91117      65.38462 13.444444       71.91117   CHD     1
22 AL13-PRD-C1   100 nonlinear 114.25 19.25 55.25 1.34650 1.48375 33.1800 115.250 12.775  6.275  7.975 1178.25  574.75 220.375 52.350      85.5       84.23522      76.92308 15.748538       84.23522   CHD     1
23 AL13-PRD-C1   115 nonlinear 125.25 20.75 63.75 1.45100 1.65775 32.6450 117.500 14.100  6.875  8.825 1095.25  534.25 236.575 50.200      85.5       90.77260      88.46154 16.970760       90.77260   CHD     1
24 AL13-PRD-C1   130 nonlinear 136.25 24.75 78.00 1.59850 1.89075 30.9000 119.150 15.575  7.600  9.700  968.25  472.25 231.075 51.600      85.5      100.00000     100.00000 18.695906      100.00000   CHD     1
25 AL13-PRD-C2    25 nonlinear  60.25 15.75 19.00 0.56950 0.46550 32.2575 154.625  9.450  4.700  6.075 1597.75  794.75 348.975 44.850      82.4       30.83378      15.62500  6.911408       30.83378   CHD     2
26 AL13-PRD-C2    40 nonlinear  63.25 14.25 19.50 0.63175 0.52325 33.5700 143.225  9.275  4.625  5.975 1631.75  811.50 326.325 44.575      82.4       34.20411      25.00000  7.666869       34.20411   CHD     2
27 AL13-PRD-C2    55 nonlinear  72.75 15.75 25.00 0.82600 0.69925 34.4600 147.350 10.175  5.075  6.525 1497.25  744.75 312.475 47.950      82.4       44.72117      34.37500 10.024272       44.72117   CHD     2
28 AL13-PRD-C2    70 nonlinear  79.00 15.50 30.75 0.94525 0.86850 34.9675 153.575 11.925  5.925  7.675 1257.00  625.25 271.525 56.625      82.4       51.17759      43.75000 11.471481       51.17759   CHD     2
29 AL13-PRD-C2    85 nonlinear  88.25 16.00 37.50 1.15050 1.08025 35.6175 155.200 13.325  6.625  8.550 1127.00  560.50 282.300 54.975      82.4       62.29020      53.12500 13.962379       62.29020   CHD     2
30 AL13-PRD-C2   100 nonlinear  99.00 16.75 44.75 1.29925 1.31475 35.6475 154.150 14.775  7.325  9.500 1030.75  512.50 285.350 54.500      82.4       70.34380      62.50000 15.767597       70.34380   CHD     2
31 AL13-PRD-C2   115 nonlinear 107.00 18.00 50.00 1.39775 1.45600 36.0325 161.000 16.675  8.300 10.725  898.00  446.50 282.850 57.175      82.4       75.67677      71.87500 16.962985       75.67677   CHD     2
32 AL13-PRD-C2   130 nonlinear 118.50 21.00 61.50 1.55100 1.73675 34.8775 162.300 18.300  9.100 11.750  815.75  405.75 276.700 58.700      82.4       83.97401      81.25000 18.822816       83.97401   CHD     2
33 AL13-PRD-C2   145 nonlinear 128.25 24.25 74.75 1.71275 1.99100 33.3300 161.025 19.925  9.900 12.800  749.50  372.75 267.875 60.175      82.4       92.73146      90.62500 20.785801       92.73146   CHD     2
34 AL13-PRD-C2   160 nonlinear 142.50 29.00 90.50 1.84700 2.21650 30.9325 154.750 20.925 10.425 13.425  715.50  355.75 272.250 57.100      82.4      100.00000     100.00000 22.415049      100.00000   CHD     2
```

I made prediction with this function:
`mod=lm(cbind(power,hr,percent_absVO2,relVO2,percent_relVO2)~percent_power*id+training,data=dftest)`

And I used this function to create a dataset which includes all my prediction I have made before:

```
tst=setNames(
  data.frame(
    expand.grid(unique(df_sum[,"id"]),unique(df_sum[,"training"]),seq(25,100,25))
  ), nm = c("id", "time", "power", "hr", "fr", "VE", "absVO2", "VCO2", "PETCO2", "VES", "QC", "IC", "WCI", "RVSi", "RVS", "VTD", "FE", "percent_absVO2", "relVO2", "percent_relVO2")
)
```

That comes with this error:

```
Error in names(object) <- nm : 
  'names' attribute [20] must be the same length as the vector [3]
```

Comment: Your problem is that: `data.frame(expand.grid(unique(df_sum[,"id"]),unique(df_sum[,"training"]),seq(25,100,25)))` only has 3 columns, while your dataset has way more. Try executing each piece of code and see if you get what you expect, then maybe read `help(function)` replacing "function" with the name of the function that didn't give you what you'd expect.

Comment: I am sorry, I am naive to that. I have entered the name of the column of my dataset. I don't know how to do, even after looking at the help.

Comment: Your dataset has 20 different column names. The first problem is that you're not creating a dataframe with *all* 20 columns, but only 3 (ID, Training and then `seq(25, 100, 25)`. You would need to create all of: "time", "power", "hr", "fr", "VE", "absVO2", "VCO2", "PETCO2", "VES", "QC", "IC", "WCI", "RVSi", "RVS", "VTD", "FE", "percent_absVO2", "relVO2", "percent_relVO2"

Comment: Thanks, it is working now !